# Codeforces #806 Problem D: Double Strings

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, hash-map

I tried solving the following [problem](https://codeforces.com/contest/1703/problem/D) by following the suggested approach to solving the problem in the problem tutorial. However, the online judge still says my solution exceeds the time limit. Is there a way to optimize the program to perform faster?

## The Problem:

> You are given \$n\$ strings \$s_1, s_2, \dots, s_n\$ of length at most 8.
>
> For each string \$s_i\$, determine if there exist two strings \$s_j\$ and \$s_k\$ such that \$s_i = s_j + s_k\$. That is, \$s_i\$ is the concatenation of \$s_j\$ and \$s_k\$. Note that \$j\$ *can* be equal to \$k\$.
>
> Recall that the concatenation of strings \$s\$ and \$t\$ is \$s + t = s_1 s_2 \dots s_p t_1 t_2 \dots p_q\$, where \$p\$ and \$q\$ are the lengths of strings \$s\$ and \$t\$ respectively. For example, concatenation of "code" and "forces" is "codeforces".
>
> ### Input
>
> The first line contains a single integer \$t\$ (\$1 \leq t \leq 10^4\$) — the number of test cases.
>
> The first line of each test case contains a single integer \$n\$ (\$1 \leq n \leq 10^5\$) — the number of strings.
>
> Then \$n\$ lines follow, the \$i\$-th of which contains non-empty string \$s_i\$ of length at most 8, consisting of lowercase English letters. Among the given \$n\$ strings, there may be duplicates.
>
> The sum of \$n\$ over all test cases doesn't exceed \$10^5\$.
>
> ### Output
>
> For each test case, output a binary string of length \$n\$. The \$i\$-th bit should be 1 if there exist two strings \$s_j\$ and \$s_k\$ where \$s_i = s_j + s_k\$, and 0 otherwise. Note that \$j\$ can be equal to \$k\$.
>
> ### Example
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> 3
> 5
> abab
> ab
> abc
> abacb
> c
> 3
> x
> xx
> xxx
> 8
> codeforc
> es
> codes
> cod
> forc
> forces
> e
> code
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 10100
> 011
> 10100101
> ```
>
> ### The Problem Tutorial (Hint):
>
> Use some data structure that allows you to answer queries of the form: "does the string \$t\$ appear in the array \$s_1, \dots, s_n\$?" For example, in C++ you can use a `map<string, bool>`, while in Python you can use a dictionary.
>
> Afterwards, for each string \$s\$, brute force all strings \$x\$ and \$y\$ such that \$s=x+y\$. There are at most 7 such strings, because \$s\$ has length at most 8. Then check if both \$x\$ and \$y\$ appear in the array using your data structure.
>
> The time complexity is \$O(ℓ n \log n)\$ per test case, where \$ℓ\$ is the maximum length of an input string.

## My Solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int tests;
    cin >> tests;

    for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++) { //one loop per each test case
        int NumOfStrings;
        cin >> NumOfStrings;

        unordered_map<string, bool> phrases;
        string words[100000];

        for (int j = 0; j < NumOfStrings; j++) { // adds all input strings for each test case into words and phrases
            string temp;
            cin >> temp;
            phrases.insert({ temp, false });
            words[j] = temp;
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < NumOfStrings; k++) { // loop for each string in the test case
            int len = words[k].length(); // len is length of current word
            for (int o = 0; o < len; o++) { // loops through current word
                string partition1 = "";
                string partition2 = "";
                for (int m = 0; m <= o; m++) {
                    partition1 += words[k][m];
                }
                for (int n = o+1; n < len; n++) {
                    partition2 += words[k][n];
                }
                if (phrases.find(partition1) != phrases.end() && phrases.find(partition2) != phrases.end()) { //if both substrings exist in the map, then value for word is 1.
                    phrases[words[k]] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < NumOfStrings; j++) {
            int value = 0;
            if (phrases[words[j]] == true) value = 1;
            cout << value;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I thought code review SE was for code that already works as intended. if it doesn't it probably belongs on SO

Comment: @qwr Too inefficient (time or space) is the one failure we accept here.

Answer (score 4):

You are failing with the datastructures.

What you need is:

1. A string to mark your answers.
   Start with all no.
2. A `std::vector` to collect your strings.
3. A way to identify all candidates for the prefix fast.
   A sorted `std::vector` will do.

   - You might want to get fancy when iterating it to identify candidates even faster.
   - Don't forget to include the id to mark your answers.
4. A way to test existence of a matching suffix.
   A hashset will do fabulously.

And for the love of all, *don't* duplicate strings for the two datastructures, use `std::string_view`.

As you only use it once it's not that bad, but you really don't need the manual flush in `std::endl`. And if you did need it, you should still be explicit and use `std::flush`.

Comment: Now I'm questioning my beliefs whether `unordered_set` is almost always faster than `set`. I had a solution using `unordered_set` rejected with "time limit exceeded" verdict, but the one using `set` was accepted. I packed strings into `unsigned long long` integers and used bit operations.

Answer (score 0):

### Move solution into a separate function

Doing this greatly improves code readability.

```
void solve() {
  int NumOfStrings;
  /* ... */      
}

int main() {
  int t;
  cin >> t;
  while (t--)
    solve();
  return 0;
}
```

### Be careful about using resources

On each iteration, we do a lot of redundant work by creating and destroying 100k strings.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++) { //one loop per each test case
  string words[100000];
}
```

Presumably, heap allocation is not involved due to the [small string optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring/10319672).

To optimize memory usage, make the array `static`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++) { //one loop per each test case
  static string words[100000];
}
```

### Misleading hint

Before checking the author's solution, I didn't quite understand the purpose of using `map`.
Let's find it out.

```
void solve() {
  /* ... */
  map<string, bool> mp;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> s[i];
    mp[s[i]] = true; // map input string to true
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    /* ... */
    /* mp[pref] adds pair {pref, false} to mp
       if pref is not presented and returns false;
       otherwise, returns true if pref is an input string */        
    if (mp[pref] && mp[suff]) { ok = true; }        
  /* ... */
}
```

The author's `map` gradually growths, but only input strings are mapped to `true`.

Looks like the hint was misinterpreted, which is not surprising because it had been taken out of the context.

```
for (int k = 0; k < NumOfStrings; k++) { // loop for each string in the test case
  /* ... */
    if (phrases.find(partition1) != phrases.end() && phrases.find(partition2) != phrases.end()) { //if both substrings exist in the map, then value for word is 1.
      phrases[words[k]] = true;
    }
  }
}

for (int j = 0; j < NumOfStrings; j++) {
  int value = 0;
  if (phrases[words[j]] == true) value = 1;
  cout << value;
}
```

Needlessly changing mapped values to check them later in the separate loop, is a lot of redundant work.
Searching for partitions is the only crucial part here, which may be performed with a set instead of `map`.

### In conclusion

It suffices to apply the proposed improvements to make your solution accepted.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

void solve()
{
  int NumOfStrings;
  cin >> NumOfStrings;

  unordered_set<string> phrases;
  static string words[100000];

  for (int j = 0; j < NumOfStrings; j++) { // adds all input strings for each test case into words and phrases
    string temp;
    cin >> temp;
    phrases.insert(temp);
    words[j] = temp;
  }

  for (int k = 0; k < NumOfStrings; k++) { // loop for each string in the test case
    int len = words[k].length(); // len is length of current word
    bool ok = false;
    for (int o = 0; o < len; o++) { // loops through current word
      string partition1 = "";
      string partition2 = "";
      for (int m = 0; m <= o; m++) {
        partition1 += words[k][m];
      }
      for (int n = o+1; n < len; n++) {
        partition2 += words[k][n];
      }
      if (phrases.find(partition1) != phrases.end() && phrases.find(partition2) != phrases.end()) { //if both substrings exist in the map, then value for word is 1.
        ok = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    cout << ok;
  }

  cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
  int tests;
  cin >> tests;

  while (tests--)
    solve();

  return 0;
}
```